# Extracting part of list from another list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists. One list just has elements in a random order (`y`), while another ordered list has list subsets (`x`). The first elements of those list subsets are the same as the random list.

I want all the elements from the second list which are present in the first list, but in the same order. Here is an example:

Input:

```
x = [[1,'a'],[2,'b'],[3,'c'],[4,'d'],[5,'d']]
y = [4,1,2]
```

Required Output:

```
[[4, 'd'], [1, 'a'], [2, 'b']] # Same sequence as y but elements in x
```

I have written some code to accomplish this:

```
for i in range(0,len(y)):
    for k in range(0,len(x)):
        if y[i] ==x[k][0]:
            d.append(x[k])
```

However, I am not sure if this is the most efficient way to go about this. This is just an example, in reality, my list `x` contains over a million sub lists and so if I try to use this code, it will loop over `x` a million times.

How can I make this code more efficient?

Comment: How big is `y`? Only a few elements like in the example or as big as `x`?

Comment: Also, are any first elements repeated (for example, `4` appears as a first element more than once)? The answers depend on whether or not they are.

Comment: Are values in y indexes in x?

Answer (score 3):

Is there any reason you can't use a dictionary (i.e., are the first elements ever repeated?) and do something like:

```
>>> d = {1: "a", 2: "b", 3: "c", 4: "d", 5: "d"}
>>> map(lambda x: [x,d.get(x)], [4,1,2])
[[4, 'd'], [1, 'a'], [2, 'b']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your list of lists to a dict and then just loop over your `y` list while doing a list comprehension like so

```
x = [[1,'a'],[2,'b'],[3,'c'],[4,'d'],[5,'d']]
d = dict(x)
y=[4,1,2]
newlist = [[i,d[i]] for i in y]
print newlist
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to first filter elements that have their first item existing in `y` then sorting the resulting list same order as `y`:

```
>>> x
[[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c'], [4, 'd'], [5, 'd']]
>>> y
[4, 1, 2]
>>> l = filter(lambda s:s[0] in y, x)
>>> l
[[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [4, 'd']]
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda s: y.index(s[0]))
[[4, 'd'], [1, 'a'], [2, 'b']]
```